# Remove style from prev/next element when hovering on element

Tags: html, css, hover, border

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JUmHG/3

When mouse is over on a LI, the top/bottom border of the LI becomes transparent (replaced by background-color).

But also the bottom-border of the previous LI and the top-border of the next LI must be transparent as well. Can this be done with CSS ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot select the previous sibling, but you can try some tricks to get the desired effect.

Like this:

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JUmHG/8/)

Use just `border-top` & an `inset` `box-shadow` on every list item but the fist one in order to mimic the etched top border.

```
li{
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}    
li:first-child{
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Then remove it on `hover` for the current item and the item that comes right after it.

```
li:hover, li:hover + li {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

This works in all [browsers that support `box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) (that is, everything except IE8 and older and less capable mobile browsers).

The same effect could be achieved in IE8 by using an absolutely positioned pseudo-element that is given `top: 0; left: 0; height: 1px; width: 100%; background: #fff;` (and even in IE7, by adding a child to the list item instead of the pseudo-element). However, I think it's overkill, especially since the original method degrades gracefully.

Comment: Just when I think something is impossible to achieve, you come up with such a clever trick, @Ana :)

Answer (score 3):

The best I could do was the next, but not the previous:

http://jsfiddle.net/JUmHG/4/

The above uses the CSS `+` selector, which selects the next sibling.

To style the previous `li,` you might need JavaScript.

For a jQuery solution this might work: http://jsfiddle.net/JUmHG/5/

When CSS4 comes along (don't hold your breath), you will be able to do this though (the subject selector):

```
$li + li:hover,
li:hover,
li:hover + li {
    ...
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#subject

Answer (score 1):

JQuery:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
  $(this).prev().addClass('hide'); 
},function(){
  $( 'li').removeClass('hide'); 
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
   border-color: transparent;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JUmHG/6/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the above:

1. Provide only border-top for all the `<li>` elements except the first one.

   > `li{ border-top: 1px solid #fff; padding: 10px;}`
2. To remove border from first `<li>` element, use:

   > `li:first-child {border-top: none;}`
3. Add hover state css like below:

   > `li:hover{ border-color: transparent; background: #ccc; border-radius: 7px; }`
4. Remove next sibling `<li>` element's border on hover of current `<li>` element:

   > `li:hover + li { border-top: none; }`

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/egafb63s/1/)

Comment: PS: This is first ever answer on stack overflow, feel free to correct me.